# How can I get an AJAX call to NOT finish before my handlebar template is done loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, handlebars.js

I am using a handlebars template to stick some info on my nav bar. The info is coming from a Rails controller via an AJAX call. The AJAX, given that it's asynchronous, is finishing after the template has received it's variables, thus a variable that should be set in the AJAX call never does so. Here's the code:

```
export default {
  name: "data-menu-item",

  initialize: function(container) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var source                 = $("#notification-menu-item").html();
      var template               = Handlebars.compile(source);
      var user                   = Discourse.User.current();
      var pro                    = false;
      var logged_user            = false;
      var data_url               = "";


    $.ajax("/custom_group_names", {
      type: 'GET'
    }).done(function(res){
      if(res.custom_group_names){
        console.log(res.group_names);
        for (var i=0; i < res.group_names.length; i++) {
          // Agents, Brokers, ManagingBrokers, MortageBrokers, admins
          if (res.group_names[i]["name"] === "Brokers" || res.group_names[i]["name"] === "ManagingBrokers" || res.group_names[i]["name"] === "MortageBrokers") {
            console.log("groups were brokers, etc.");
            pro = true;
            data_url = "twobydev.com/brokerdashboard";
          } else if (res.group_names[i]["name"] === "admins" || res.group_names[i]["name"] === "Agents") {
            console.log("groups were admin or agents");
            pro = true;
            data_url = "twobydev.com/agentdashboard";
            console.log(pro);
            console.log(data_url);
          }
        }
      }
    });

      if(user) {
        logged_user = true;
        if(user.total_unread_notifications > 0) {
          new_notification_class = "new-notifications"
          notification_count = "(" + user.total_unread_notifications + ")";
        }
      }

      var html = template({pro: pro, logged_user: logged_user, data_url: data_url});
      $('body').prepend(html);
    });
  }
}
```

`logged_user` gets set because it is outside of the ajax call, however, I need `pro` and `data_url` to be set as well. Any advice or help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move this...

```
if(user) {
    logged_user = true;
    if(user.total_unread_notifications > 0) {
        new_notification_class = "new-notifications"
        notification_count = "(" + user.total_unread_notifications + ")";
    }
}

var html = template({pro: pro, logged_user: logged_user, data_url: data_url});
$('body').prepend(html);
```

inside of your `done` function.

Comment: Not a good idea. Is now deprecated and browser vendors are throwing warnings into console. This has always been a bad practice since it is blocking to the UI

Comment: @charlietfl Obvs bad practice but didn't know it was deprecated so fair point... removed the async option ;) Side note, he needs to also move his `if(user){...}` code block inside `done` too right?

Comment: Yes, probably should... I went for showing concept without complete re-write

Answer (score 1):

Move the template processing into the ajax callback

```
function processTemplate(){
    var html = template({pro: pro, logged_user: logged_user, data_url: data_url});
      $('body').prepend(html);
}

$.ajax({
   .....

}).done(function(res){
  /* existing processing code */

  // now process template
  processTemplate()
});
```